# Set form location c#

Tags: c#, forms, location

I would like to know how to set my form position. i have tried to do the following:

```
this.Location = Point;
```

or:

```
Form2.Left = Point.X;
Form2.Top = Point.Y;
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

This is does not work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is not working? Your form is not positioned properly or the form is not displayed on the screen at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form();

    form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    form2.Left = 500;
    form2.Top  = 500;
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: this is better then using `new Point(x,y)` alternative, because no need to add reference yo `System.Drawing.dll`

Comment: Would be nice from Microsoft to throw some notification exception (such as "threadAbort" exception) if not set "StartPosition" to manual. This is annoying you don't find out why your position isn't set

Answer (score 1):

to set the position programmatically  , you should set **StartPosition** to **FormStartPosition.Manual** as shown below :

```
Form myform = new Form()
{
     Size = new Size(200,200),
     StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
     Location = new Point(10,10) // or Cursor.Position if you want to set it to cursor position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SetDesktopLocation(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Point(specify location of x, specify location of y)
// with object initializer
var frmUsers = new FrmUsers
{
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual, 
    Location = new Point(0, 0)
};

// or

var frmUsers = new FrmUsers();
frmUsers.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
frmUsers.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Comment: Have in mind that answers which contains only code are not considered complete

Answer (score 0):

The first approach of you works anyways.

```
this.Location = new Point(/*XPosition*/, /*YPosition*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this:

```
form1.Location = new Point(4, 370);
```